# Using %n or \n in Java to format String

Tags: java, format

What is the difference between %n and \n in Java?

For example,

```
System.out.printf("Hello, world! %n");
```

and

```
System.out.printf("Hello, world! \n");
```

Both return the same output for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as far as i know the difference is that `%n` will always output the correct line break depending on the platform while `\n` won't.