# \n and %n in recursion of printing string (Java)

Tags: java

I'm a newbie here in Java. I use the "javac" and "java" terminal command to compile and run my codes in my mac. Though I've read this article [Using %n or \n in Java to format String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366242/using-n-or-n-in-java-to-format-string) , I still don't understand why it keeps infinitely prints "Happy Birthday" with a line break if "\n" stays in the code. What I want was just an extra blank line after the line of the string. And after I tried to replace "\n" with "%n", it just prints "Happy Birthday! %n" instead of giving me a line break. What's wrong with the "\n" and why isn't "%n" working in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HappyBirthday{

            public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            int n = s.nextInt();

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

                    System.out.println("Happy Birthday! \n");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: As you are using `println` you do not need to add your EOL char `System.out.println("Happy Birthday!");` is fine

Comment: @Scary sorry, i did not put my question clear enough, What I want was  an extra blank line after the line of the string. So I want an new blank line  after System.out.println("Happy Birthday!"); to be written in one line instead of writing another line of System.out.println("\n"); or something alike.

Comment: Sorry I can not understand your problem then.  My code `  System.out.println("hello\n");
  System.out.println("hello2");`  prints `hello
<newline>
hello2
`

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, your code works fine with me, but my code which nest the printing statement in a for recursion turns out to have problem. Or could you test my code for me please?

Comment: Looks fine `3
Happy Birthday! 
<newline>
Happy Birthday! 
<newline>
Happy Birthday! `